# Django: How do I get the username of the logged-in user in my class based view?

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I have implemented a DeleteView and would like it to redirect it to the logged-in user's profile after deleting the object:

```
class DeleteAttendanceFeedItem(DeleteView, LoginRequiredMixin):
    model = AttendanceFeedItem
    template_name = "users/delete_attendance_feed_item.html"
    context_object_name = "attendance_feed_item"
    success_url = reverse_lazy("user_profile", kwargs={"username" : request.user.username})
```

I don't have access to the request object in a class-based view, though. Searching StackOverflow suggests I have access to self.request.user.username, but that's throwing the same error.

This seems like a very simple thing that I have burned a surprisingly large amount of time reading SO and Django documentation to absolutely no avail. Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **`self.request.user.username`** to get the username inside the [`get_success_url()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.get_success_url) method

```
class DeleteAttendanceFeedItem(DeleteView, LoginRequiredMixin):
    model = AttendanceFeedItem
    template_name = "users/delete_attendance_feed_item.html"
    context_object_name = "attendance_feed_item"

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy("user_profile", kwargs={"username": self.request.user.username})
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I knew it would be something simple! I did see this method referenced, but I was trying to do something silly where I defined the function but then did `success_url = get_success_url()`, which made this not possible. I'm really appreciative that you cleared it up for me! I'll accept your answer when I can in 10 minutes.